# Create images patches with overlap using torch.unfold

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to split an images into smaller images of 1024x1024. I would like to have an overlap of 100 pixels in the top/bottom and left/right of the patches.

[image]

I am using padding and torch.unfold to create even sized patches.

```
def create_patches(image, patch_size):
    # Pad right and bottom to fit patch_size
    padding_right = patch_size - image.shape[2]%patch_size
    padding_bottom = patch_size - image.shape[1]%patch_size
    image = F.pad(image, (0, 0, padding_right, padding_bottom))
    return image.unfold(0, 3, 3).unfold(1, patch_size, patch_size).unfold(2, patch_size, patch_size)
```

How can I make the patches to overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your input shape is `(height, width, n_channels)` and the expected output shape is `(patches_n_rows, patches_n_cols, patch_size, patch_size, n_channels)`.

1. To make patches overlap, the step should be the size of the patch minus the size of the overlap.
2. Then we calculate the width that needs to be padded. If not padded, the excess width of the image is `(width - overlap) % step`, where `overlap` is the size of the overlap. If the excess width is not 0, the width to be padded is `step - excess_width`. The calculation method for the height to be padded is the same.
3. Next, according to the documentation, the parameter `pad` for `F.pad` should be `(last dim left pad, last dim right pad, 2nd to last dim left pad, 2nd to last dim right pad, ...)`. Here, it should be `(0, 0, 0, padding_width, 0, padding_height)`.
4. After padding the image and `unfold` the first two axes, we will get the shape `(patches_n_rows, patches_n_cols, n_channels, patch_size, patch_size)` (`unfold` always puts new dimension at the last) and need to apply `moveaxis` once finally.

In summary, the code is as follows:

```
def create_patches(image, patch_size=1024, overlap=100):
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    step = patch_size - overlap
    padding_width = (step - (width - overlap) % step) % step
    padding_height = (step - (height - overlap) % step) % step
    image = F.pad(image, (0, 0, 0, padding_width, 0, padding_height))
    return (
        image
        .unfold(0, patch_size, step)
        .unfold(1, patch_size, step)
        .moveaxis(2, -1)
    )
```

Test:

```
>>> image = torch.rand(2160, 3840, 4)
>>> patches = create_patches(image)
>>> patches.shape
torch.Size([3, 5, 1024, 1024, 4])
>>> 
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> # overlap detection for each row
>>> all(
...     torch.equal(left[:, -100:], right[:, :100])
...     for i in range(patches.size(0))
...     for left, right in pairwise(patches[i])
... )
True
>>> # overlap detection for each column
>>> all(
...     torch.equal(up[-100:], down[:100])
...     for j in range(patches.size(1))
...     for up, down in pairwise(patches[:, j])
... )
True
```